# Built-in server redirects my links to roots

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I don't know why, but when I use the built-in server from the CLI, my relatives links doesn't work. For exemple I have a :

```
<a href="article.php" class="post__link">Continue reading</a>
```

And the link leads to this error :
*The requested resource **/article.php** was not found on this server.*

Article.php and index.php are in /php directory.
I did not add this slash myself, how do I change this behaviour please?
I have tried to put ./article.php, /./article.php, it doesn't work.

Comment: And `/php` is your root directory? How/from which folder did you start the "built-in" server?

Comment: Nope /php is not my root-directory, I start the server from his parent.
Btw I also tried php -S localhost:8000 -t php for what it worth.

Comment: And to be very clear, `/php/article.php` does work?

Comment: If I type myself the url in the research bar ? Yes it works, only the link is broken, to simplify my problem, it seems the server considers all my links in absolute path for no reason.